# How to type function return type from passed in generic array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to convert Bytes to Kb, Mb or both. The function should return an object using the expected conversion type(s) as key and number as value. Following is the function

```js
export function formatFromBytes<TSize extends ('kilobyte' | 'megabyte')[]>(
  bytes: number,
  get: TSize,
  useDecimal = false,
): Record<keyof TSize, number> {
  const marker = useDecimal ? 1000 : 1024; // One Kilobyte

  const decimal = 0;

  return get.reduce((acc, cv) => {
    switch (cv) {
      case 'kilobyte':
        acc[cv] = +(bytes / marker).toFixed(decimal);
        break;

      case 'megabyte':
        const megaBytes = marker * marker; // One MB
        acc[cv] = +(bytes / megaBytes).toFixed(decimal);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<keyof TSize, number>);
}
```

When used

```js
formatFromBytes(5000000, ['megabyte']).megabyte
//                                    ^ // TS2339: Property 'megabyte' does not exist on type 'Record '.
```

What is wrong here? How to correct it?

Comment: `TSize` is not an object type with keys, it's an array type. To get the element type, use `TSize[number]` not `keyof TSize` in your `Record`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite it a little bit:

```js
type ReduceUnits<Units extends string[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Units as Units[Prop] extends string ? Units[Prop] : never]: number
}


export function formatFromBytes<Unit extends 'kilobyte' | 'megabyte', Units extends Unit[]>(
    bytes: number,
    get: [...Units],
    useDecimal = false,
): ReduceUnits<Units> {
    const marker = useDecimal ? 1000 : 1024; // One Kilobyte

    const decimal = 0;

    return get.reduce((acc, cv) => {
        switch (cv) {
            case 'kilobyte': {
                return {
                    ...acc,
                    [cv]: +(bytes / marker).toFixed(decimal)
                }
            }

            case 'megabyte': {
                const megaBytes = marker * marker; // One MB here
                return {
                    ...acc,
                    [cv]: +(bytes / megaBytes).toFixed(decimal)
                }
            }

            default: {
                return acc
            }
        }

    }, {} as ReduceUnits<Units>);
}

const _ = formatFromBytes(100, ['kilobyte']).kilobyte//ok
const __ = formatFromBytes(100, ['kilobyte','megabyte'])
__.kilobyte // ok
__.megabyte // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZVvPm)

Take a look on `ReduceUnits`. To understand it better, please check [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). TL DR, it goes through keys and remaps each key according to `as` expression. IN our example, `Prop` represents array index, hence `Units[Prop]` just returns a value from array by index.

Also, I used `get: [...Units]` to infer literal type of provided memory units.

**EXPLANATION** of `ReduceUnits`
Consider this simple iteration:

```js
type ReduceUnits_1<Units extends string[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Units]: Prop
}

// type Result = ["0", "1"]

type Result = ReduceUnits_1<['a', 'b']>
```

Result is expected `["0", "1"]`, because we are iterating through an array, and `Prop` in `ReduceUnits_1` is just a key in array. And `key` in array is just an index. Because arrays in JS is smth similar to

```js
const array = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b'
}
```

It might be confusing that I have used `as` inside type iterator. To learn more about this technique you should read [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). Lets try a simple example:

```js
type ReduceUnits_1<Units extends string[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Units as `${Exclude<Prop,symbol>}-suffix`]: Prop
}


type Result = ReduceUnits_1<['a', 'b']>
```

`as` assertion renames a key. However, here you got a weird result with all Array.prototype.methods. We don't want to take them into account, we want only get an array key which corresponds to value. In this example, we are interested only in indexes because only they corresponds to value in array.

```js
type ReduceUnits_1<Units extends string[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Units as Units[Prop] extends string ? Units[Prop] : never]: Prop
}
```

This is why , after `as` assertion I have added conditional type:

```js
Units[Prop] extends string ? Units[Prop] : never
```

If `Units[Prop]` is a string, then it means that `Prop` is an index, hence, condition statement should return `Units[Prop]` (['a','b'][0]). Which in fact, transforms iterated index to a value which corresponds to this index.
You can refactor this and write smth like this:

```js
type Transform<Units extends string[],Prop extends keyof Units>=Units[Prop] extends string ? Units[Prop] : never

type ReduceUnits_1<Units extends string[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Units as Transform<Units, Prop>]: Prop
}
```

Comment: Marvelous. You're awesome. Thank you for the explanation too. But unfortunately, I need a little help to understand it. As far as I understand by this `Unit extends 'kilobyte' | 'megabyte', Units extends Unit[]` is that you've taken `Unit` generic to build up an array of that generic & you've set constraint of `kilobyte` & `megabyte` on the unit so other values can't be passed. Can you please explain a bit this part `[Prop in keyof Units as Units[Prop] extends string? Units[Prop] : never]` in `ReduceUnits` type? especially from (after) `Units as`

Comment: @Md.A.Apu provided you with more explanation

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you very much, This helped me a lot & I'm sure this will help many like me.

Comment: can you help me with the similar thing? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76649582/5420070
It's my bad that still I need help understanding that.

Comment: @Md.A.Apu sure, no problem. It took me a lot of time to understand TS, don't worry about that