# How to type a function that takes string or string array & return capitalized version of that string or string array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Following is the function. This should only take `string` or `string[]` & make capital `string` or `string[]`

```js
export function capitalize(input: string | string[]) {
  const doCapitalize = (str: string) => {
    const capital = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    return `${capital}${str.slice(1)}`;
  };

  if (typeof input == 'string') {
    return doCapitalize(input);
  }

  return input.map((s) => doCapitalize(s));
}
```

Want full completion like

```js
const cap = capitalize('capital');
cap === '' //Capital
// and
const cap = capitalize(['capitalA', 'capitalB']);
cap[0] === '' //CapitalA
```

Made something in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShAmBXAxhAwgQzAS2BgNtgF4QA8AKgJIB2YiwUEAHsBNfAM5QfABO21AOYBtALoA%20KAF4owgAq8A9mCgCoAawghFAMyhVa9KBi4G6weUrCjGLNp258BgqAH4omHHkIkKNc5bKElAAXFDUEABuELyiANxQAPSJ3IoAthDAABbOUISaUNnYHK4AUKXMYIq8DDqI1MjA2IrUUMhYuATEZGZGzKzsXDz8QuIAFALmYb3AAJRhnp0%20Pf704nEVTFU1UHUNTS1tHd7dfoYM-fZDTkJi45P006tzYXBIqIsnvjPrm9u19UazVa7S8XRIE3OYWGuQAPo4RiJRPNjNQQFAAN6lKBtFo8KDwRSfcHQGRjYbQm6CWbSSRYnE45B4higpbSBEAOmQWQwvAAgsAxgAGWYc4CKACqYEgvEwHAgY1mGwZUF4mUQvFaAAMACQY1neAC%20euGHI4hFQYwAjLNDVrlVBDRtsao9GNQJBdKpztIZAByGFCP00%20kMtXADWtQnE5aQ8xKl2G8o48OR73mDlpLBjck0qSSaPHEm5hNJ0pM6j40FW9kG4t%20jAAI2Q8GDG2SKoAemVy8yjmAAEy1oux4QN5utgA0UD9EB0giyfuR7ZSDO75VBA7HQqXvpnfqSKQ4WUUiHw8G4iEEggg%20IARHyJ3egA) that didnt work

Comment: There is a built-in [`Capitalize` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). Besides that, it's not clear what part you have trouble with, exactly.

Comment: How this will help when `string[]` is provided?

Comment: Yep, the idea in your Playgroud is good (the implementation, less so; for the array, `{[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? Capitalize<T[P]> : never}` will do better, I think). But you have to declare your array `as const`, otherwise they'll be considered as `string[]` rather than `['capitalA', 'capitalB']` before even reaching your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider this example:

```js
function doCapitalize<Str extends string>(str: Str): Capitalize<Str>
function doCapitalize<Str extends string>(str: Str) {
    const capital = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    return `${capital}${str.slice(1)}`;
};

const _ = doCapitalize('hello') // "Hello"


type MapCapitalize<List extends string[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof List]: Capitalize<List[Prop]>
}

export function capitalize<Input extends string[]>(input: [...Input]): MapCapitalize<Input>
export function capitalize<Input extends string>(input: Input): Capitalize<Input>
export function capitalize(input: string | string[]) {
    if (typeof input == 'string') {
        return doCapitalize(input);
    }

    return input.map((s) => doCapitalize(s));
}

const __ = capitalize(['one', 'two']) // ["One", "Two"]
const ___ = capitalize('one') // "One"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m07VPN)

THis example is similar to **@Romain LAURENT** answer, however, I am using rest elements  `[...Input]` for type inference. Thanks to that, you don't need to use `as const` assertion.
Also, you can move  `doCapitalize` out of scope and make it separate function.

P.S. @Romain LAURENT was first hence I do believe that they deserve to get accepted answer

---

I have added an overloading to `doCapitalize` because `String.prototype.toUpperCase` returns `string` which is a supertype.
`Capitalized` in turn is subtype for more broader type `string`. Hence, you are not allowed to assign `string` to `Capitalize`.
Consider this example:

```js
declare let str: string;
declare let capitalize: Capitalize<string>

str = capitalize // ok

capitalize = str // error
```

As you might have noticed, `str` is not assignable to `capitalize` because `str` can be any string and `capitalize` can be only capitalized, whereas any capitalized string is a string and can be assignable to string.

This is exactly what happens in `daCapitalized`.
`${capital}${str.slice(1)}` is just a string and you want to return `Capitalized<string>`, hence you are trying to assign regular any string to `Capitalized`.

Comment: Thank you again, you're a genius. Your answer is perfectly aligned with my expectations.  So I'm accepting your answer but I highly appreciate all the knowledge everybody shared & enlighten us (me & the future person who learns from this)

Comment: One thing I'm not getting is why you've added an overload to `doCapitalize` fn instead of using the return type directly in `doCapitalize` ?

Comment: @Md.A.Apu updated an answer

Answer (score 3):

prepends the more restrictive declarations to the function:

```
export function capitalize (input: string): string;
export function capitalize (input: string[]): string[];
export function capitalize (input: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    const doCapitalize = (str: string) => {
        const capital = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        return `${capital}${str.slice(1)}`;
    };

    if (typeof input === "string") {
        return doCapitalize(input);
    }

    return input.map(s => doCapitalize(s));
}
```

EDIT :
generic versions and tuple consideration

```
export function capitalize<T extends string> (input: T): Capitalize<T>;
export function capitalize<T extends string> (input: T[]): Capitalize<T>[];
export function capitalize<T extends readonly [...string[]]> (input: T): {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? Capitalize<T[P]> : never};
export function capitalize (input: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    const doCapitalize = (str: string) => {
        const capital = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        return `${capital}${str.slice(1)}`;
    };

    if (typeof input === "string") {
        return doCapitalize(input);
    }

    return input.map(s => doCapitalize(s));
}

const A = capitalize("toto");
const B = capitalize(["titi", "tutu"]);
const C = capitalize(["toto", "tata"] as const);
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate this solution but I try to avoid `as const` whenever possible. Surely I've learned from your answer.