# Convert array literal values to object keys

Tags: typescript

I wrote a simple function to convert an array of string values into an object that I'm then able to look up with `obj[x]` compared to `array.includes(x)`. That way I can use the resulting object as an allowlist/denylist that is significantly faster:

```
function toBoolMap<A extends Array<string>>(array: A): Record<A[number], true> {
    return Object.assign({}, ...array.map(key => ({[key]: true})))
}
```

Given a list such as this:

```js
const osFiles = [
    "$RECYCLE.BIN",
    "DumpStack.log.tmp",
    "System Volume Information"
] as const
```

we'll get the following object:

```js
{
    "$RECYCLE.BIN": true,
    "DumpStack.log.tmp": true,
    "System Volume Information": true
}
```

Which works perfectly fine on the JS side.

The problem with this method is that I cannot pass a readonly array constant that is created with `as const` as a function parameter without the TS compiler throwing the `readonly cannot be assigned to the mutable type` error and neither can I make the function parameter itself immutable without making it a hard array/tuple literal.

On the other side, if I don't use `as const` the TS compiler to not recognise individual array values and the function's return type will end up as a plain record (`Record<string, true>`).

My intended result that I'm unable to get is a return type similar to the following:

```
type x = {
    "$RECYCLE.BIN": true,
    "DumpStack.log.tmp": true,
    "System Volume Information": true
}
```

How can I extract an array's values and "tell" TypeScript that these array values now became object keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function expects input array to be mutable, so you fail to pass readonly `as const`
Use `readonly` array:

```
function toBoolMap<A extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(array: A): Record<A[number], true> {
  //                         ^^^^^^^^
  return Object.assign({}, ...array.map(key => ({ [key]: true })))
}
function toBoolMap1<A extends readonly string[]>(array: A): Record<A[number], true> {
  //                          ^^^^^^^^
  return Object.fromEntries(array.map(k => [k, true])) as Record<A[number], true>
}
function toBoolMap2<K extends string>(array: readonly K[]): Record<K, true> {
  //                                         ^^^^^^^^
  return Object.fromEntries(array.map(k => [k, true])) as Record<K, true>
}

const osFiles = [
  "$RECYCLE.BIN",
  "DumpStack.log.tmp",
  "System Volume Information"
] as const

toBoolMap(osFiles)
```

Also it may be better to use `Object.fromEntries` for simplicity

Comment: This actually works perfectly.
I don't know why I haven't considered making the parameter mutable and just making its type readonly instead. Thanks for help <3

Answer (score -1):

Please consider this:

```js
const osFiles = [
    "$RECYCLE.BIN",
    "DumpStack.log.tmp",
    "System Volume Information"
] as const

type TupleToRecord<Tuple extends PropertyKey[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Tuple as Tuple[Prop] extends PropertyKey ? Tuple[Prop] : never]: true
}

function tupleToRecord<Item extends PropertyKey, Tuple extends Item[]>(tuple: [...Tuple]): TupleToRecord<Tuple>
function tupleToRecord(tuple: PropertyKey[]) {
    return tuple.reduce((acc, elem) => ({ ...acc, [elem]: true }), {})
}

const result = tupleToRecord(['a', 'b', 'c'])
result.a // true
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m07VPN)
Please see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649582/how-to-type-a-function-that-takes-string-or-string-array-return-capitalized-ve/76651209#76651209) it is related.

Comment: The `TupleToRecord` type's logic seems completely out of the read of my understanding, but it works exactly as I wanted, with the minor exception that it seems to turn the array's length into its own object key, meaning TS sees `result["3"] === true` to be valid as well.